# How to sort an index file in lucene

Tags: java, sorting, lucene, indexing

I have an index which made by lucene and each document in it have 3 filed that one of them is a numeric field which is my frequency. I search in my index but before it I want to sort it by the numeric field. is there any way to sort it by lucene  before my search?

Comment: my index have a lot of documents about 20 million.

Comment: What is the need to sort before search?

Comment: As I told I the numeric field is frequency and I want to have my result with the more frequency. any way do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @ anony - no. (other than a related link http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/misc/org/apache/lucene/index/sorter/NumericDocValuesSorter.html)

Comment: In my experience Lucene already presents search results sorted by descending score.

Comment: Did you ever find anything? Any update on this @anony ????

Answer (score 3):

Sorting *before* searching doesn't really make a lot of sense, since Lucene is creating an inverted index for searching against, rather than storing and searching through a sequential set of documents.

However, it sounds like you want to run a search and get results that are already sorted in a specified way.

This is done by passing a [Sort](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html) to the [IndexSearcher.search](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Sort%29) call, like:

```
SortField field = new SortField("frequency", SortField.Type.FLOAT);
//Sorting, first, by "frequency", then by relevance score
Sort sort = new Sort(field, Sort.FIELD_SCORE);
searcher.search(query, maxDocs, sort);
```

The name of the field makes me wonder if you aren't re-inventing the wheel though.  Lucene already factors term frequency into it's relevance scores.  If you want to tweak that sort of scoring, if might be a better idea to create a custom `Similarity` class to calculate scores for you, extending either [`TFIDFSimilarity`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html) or [`DefaultSimilarity`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/DefaultSimilarity.html), and overriding the method `tf`, particularly.

Comment: I know this way but it's not so useful for me because I have a big index and if I want to use this I should get the maxDocs a big number that make my search slow.notice that I want to search so many times and the query is prefix that change each time.So I need to sort the index first and then search on it with a small maxDocs to have a good search performance with the highest ranked results.

Comment: Unless I'm failing to understand what you are talking about, that is a non-issue.  Correct sorting is not dependent on the number of docs you pull from the index.  If you pass to the searcher that you want 5 docs back, it will give you the first 5 docs, based on your `Sort` (unless you are using something like `EarlyTerminatingSortingCollector`, but I assume you would have mentioned that).

Comment: You mean if I set the maxDocs in `Searcher.search` for example 5 it brings me the 5 docs with the max value of what I want to sort in the whole index ?! but I think it first brings the first 5 docs of index and then sort them based on my `Sort` however there may be another doc with more value of what I want at the end of the index or any other place that not be included the first 5! it first bring 5 docs and then sort or it sort all of the docs and then give the top 5 ?if the case I should set the maxDoc a big value to be sure that it bring all and sort them then and it make my search slow.